# Powershell Import-Module SqlServer and SQLPS dont get along

Tags: powershell, sqlps

In a current Powershell session i am running the following commands

```
Import-Module SqlServer
Import-Module SQLPS
```

The Import-Module Command for SqlServer works fine, but Import-Module command for SQLPS fails

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Import-Module SqlServer
PS C:\windows\system32> Import-Module SQLPS
Import-Module : The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Error in TypeData
"Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.NamedSmoObject": The member DefaultKeyPropertySet is already present.
Error in TypeData "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.NamedSmoObject": The member DefaultDisplayPropertySet is already
present.
Error in TypeData "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.NamedSmoObject": The member DefaultDisplayProperty is already
present.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module SQLPS
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Import-Module], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatXmlUpdateException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

I have tried removing the SqlServer module using Remove-Module command but no luck. I have a script which is Importing the SqlServer module at the start and then there are certain tasks in the script for which the SQLPS module is being used (and it fails with the above error). I am guessing that these 2 modules cannot be loaded in the same powershell session.

Comment: Have you tried using the `-Force` switch on the second `Import-Module`? Or maybe the `-NoClobber` switch if that one doesn't work?

Comment: Yes I added the -Force switch and the -NoClobber switches, it does not work

Answer (score 1):

SQLPS is the [older version](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2016/06/30/sql-powershell-july-2016-update/) of the SQLServer module and you are correct; the two are [incompatible](https://www.mikefal.net/2016/07/12/out-with-the-sqlps-in-with-the-sqlserver/). The SQLServer module is intended to replicate all functionality from the older version, however.